# php response text empty when using password_hash or password_verify

Tags: javascript, php, html, passwords

I have an application that uses javascript to get a string and POST it to a receiver php file on the server for further processing.  The receiver's job is to parse the string, pass things along, and report to javascript how stuff is going.  Recently I've tried to add password-based security to this whole shebang, but now receiver.php passes back an empty response.

What I'm finding is that if I call password_verify anywhere in the receiver (no matter what I do with it... I could even just call it without using it) the following echos in the script don't run - any responseText from those echos will be empty - and I've no idea why.  Though, if I just run the php script raw from command line, everything DOES work.

Before continuing, I would note that I am pretty new to web development and password-based security, so don't skewer me too hard.  Good news, though - unlike every OTHER problem I can find on the web, I AM getting correct hashes and correct verify-responses.

Using php 5.6.23

A scaled down version of the JS file "test.html":

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function reviewAndSubmit() {
            //bigOlString is usually built as a result of TONS of script on this page, use this as a test
            var bigOlString = "password=1234 name=test otherParams=barglebargle"
            var postString = new XMLHttpRequest();

            //build function to receive post response
            postString.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (postString.readyState == 4) {
                  window.alert("responseText: " + postString.responseText)
                }
            }

            postString.open("POST", "receivertest.php", true);
            postString.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
            postString.send(bigOlString);
        }


</script>
</head>
<body>
<button class="button" id="pushMe" onClick="reviewAndSubmit()">Why does PHP hate me so bad?</button>
```

And receivertest.php:

```
<?php

//hashed version of '1234' and debug name 'test'
$debugPass = '$2y$10$b.08/4NfawKOwrBYJqguc.AWsI3mQiGGaz1eYvfc9Uid1auQKKABm';
$debugName = 'test';

//get incoming string
$inString = file_get_contents('php://input');

//get challenge content
$challengePass = substr($inString, strpos($inString, "password=") + 9, strpos($inString, "name=") - 10); //10 because of the space
$name = substr($inString, strpos($inString, "name=") +5, (strpos($inString, "otherParams=") - strpos($inString, "name=") - 6)); //ugly!

//begin authentication
$auth = False;
echo $name;
echo $challengePass;


password_verify($challengePass, $debugPass); //yes, I'm not doing anything with this.  Doesn't matter.
echo "this line won't echo";
?>
```

If you comment out the 'password_verify' line in receivertest.php, everything echos perfectly.  If you don't, no luck - the 'alert' window in test.html just spits out 'responseText test123'.  If you run receivertest.php in console (php receivertest.php), however, everything echos correctly.

Why is my responseText empty?

EDIT: I've edited the php script to better illustrate the problem.  Yes, I know I'm not USING password_verify for anything.  It doesn't matter.  The 'this line won't echo' line doesn't echo out in test.html like the other lines do.  **My question is: why NOT?**

Comment: What version of PHP are you running? `password_verify` came in PHP 5.5. If you're not running PHP 5.5, you're running a dangerously old, unsupported, and thus insecure version of PHP.

Comment: You also don't seem to be doing anything *with* `password_verify`. You're echoing `true` even if the verify fails.

Comment: [The manual, always a good idea to check it](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

Comment: `if ($name == $debugName) { echo true;}` ALWAYS Regardless of what happens with the `password_verify()`

Comment: ceejoyz and RiggsFolly, please read the post.  I'm aware I'm not doing anything with password_verify in this case.  I also don't care.  What I care about is the responseText being empty.  I would LOVE if this code would always echo "true", but it ONLY does in console - it echoes NOTHING in responsetext.

Comment: @dampersand check that the request is successful. If you're on an older version PHP will probably fail when reaching the password_verify call, in production internal server errors usually don't return anything.

Comment: @JimL thanks, but as I specified in the original post, I'm on PHP5.6

Comment: @JimL also, the fact that I can run this in console from the server shows that the call is working... and I can in fact set password_verify to a bool and then var_dump the bool to see my response.  It all works... except for the echo when responding to post.

Comment: What is the HTTP status code of the response?

Comment: @ceejayoz when using password_verify, response is a generic 500.  when commenting out password_verify, response is 200.  The weird thing is that there's no error when I run receivertest.php in console - the error only seems to crop up when HTTP is involved.

Comment: @dampersand Chances are your Apache log has the error message.

Answer (score 0):

The code is all fine.  I made a quick edit in my httpd.conf file and restarted apache, and everything started working.  I undid that edit to check and restarted - everything still worked.  So I guess all I needed was an apache restart.

Apache seems to have more to do with php than I thought, I guess?